# Flash Builder project : no build done

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I created a new Flex project with Flash Builder 4. My project must used Flex 3.x (so only MX).
I copied all my sources files in my old project (created with Flex Builder 3). All is ok. I updated the argument compiler line too.

But, no build is done. Even after a project clean ... What's happen in your opinion ?

Thank you very much for your precious help !

Regards

Anthony

Comment: What happened when you selected build project from the menu?

Comment: Check you copied into the src folder.  Check the src folder is actually listed as a source folder in Project Properties > Flex Build Path.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, seemed to be caused by Flash Builder "forgetting" which file was the runnable application file.

Check out this link for more info:
http://jeremy-knight.com/2012/06/flash-builder-stops-compiling/